# Python Plotly Annotate Multiple Variables With Text

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to create a bar chart in plotly and I want to have the x and y axis blank and to show the data on the bar itself instead (I know it's contained on the hover but this is intended to be used for presentations). I've created some dummy data below.

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"]
years = [2018,2019,2020]
sales = random.sample(range(10000),18)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Year", "Month", "Sales"])

df["Year"]= years*6
df.sort_values("Year", inplace = True)
df["Month"] = months*3
df["Sales"] = sales
```

For each bar I want to see the month and the sales value so something like "Jan - 543", "Feb - 1200" etc. I'm able to add the values from a single column to the bar chart, as per below for Sales

```
barchart = px.bar(
    data_frame = df.groupby(["Month"]).Sales.sum().reset_index(),
       x = "Sales",
       y = "Month",
    title = "Sales by Month 2018-2020",
        orientation = "h",
       barmode = "group",
      text = "Sales"
       )
barchart.update_xaxes(visible = False)
barchart.update_yaxes(visible = False)
pio.show(barchart)
```

Or as per below for Months but I can't combine the two

```
barchart = px.bar(
    data_frame = df.groupby(["Month"]).Sales.sum().reset_index(),
       x = "Sales",
       y = "Month",
    title = "Sales by Month 2018-2020",
        orientation = "h",
       barmode = "group",
      text = "Month"
       )
barchart.update_xaxes(visible = False)
barchart.update_yaxes(visible = False)
pio.show(barchart)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You could skip `pio.show(barchart)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me that is more a pandas problem than a plotly one. You could create a column with the given text output and pass it to `plotly.express`

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

grp = df.groupby(["Month"])["Sales"].sum().reset_index()
grp["Text"] = grp["Month"] + " - "+ grp["Sales"].astype(str)
print(grp)
```

```
  Month  Sales         Text
0   Apr  15949  Apr - 15949
1   Feb  12266  Feb - 12266
2   Jan   9734   Jan - 9734
3   Jun  13771  Jun - 13771
4   Mar  24007  Mar - 24007
5   May  12720  May - 12720
```

and just plot `grp`

```py
barchart = px.bar(
    data_frame = grp,
    x="Sales",
    y="Month",
    title="Sales by Month 2018-2020",
    orientation ="h",
    barmode="group",
    text="Text")
barchart.update_xaxes(visible = False)
barchart.update_yaxes(visible = False)
barchart.update_layout(title_x=0.5)
```

[image]